Python - selenium - element not interactable
I know there's quite a lot in Stackoverflow (and elsewhere) about "element not interactable" but I don't think this is a duplicate.
My issue is that I get the selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException ONLY if I try to run my code in headless mode.
Here's the code. Don't worry about what it's trying to achieve other than provide a Minimal Reproducible Example
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")

QUERY = "museums in london"

# This bypasses the "automation" warning
def bypass(driver):
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
        for button in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button"))):
            if button.text.strip() == "Reject all":
                button.click()
                break
    except Exception:
        pass

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    bypass(driver)
    selector = By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'form[action="/search"] textarea[name=q]'
    textarea = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(selector))
    # The following Action sequence makes no difference to the program's behaviour
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(textarea).click(textarea).perform()
    textarea.send_keys(QUERY+Keys.RETURN)
    urls = set()
    selector = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cite[role=text]"
    for cite in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(selector)):
        if text := cite.text.strip():
            urls.add(text)
    print(*urls, sep="\n")

As shown, I'm trying to do run the Chrome driver in headless mode. If I do that I consistently get the ElementNotInteractableException at the point where I try to invoke send_keys().
If you remove the addition of the --headless argument to the ChromeOptions class, the code runs without error.
I had hoped that the ActionChains code would help but it makes no difference to the program's behaviour whether in headless mode or not. I just left it in in case anyone suggested it as a potential workaround.
Why is this only a problem when in headless mode? What can be done about it?

This is probably anti bot and anti scraping measures. Try changing the User-Agent

@Bindestrich Please explain how/why that might make a difference. Are you saying that headless mode is somehow affected by the user agent?

the user agent contains the info that you are running headless. The website has access to your user agent, it can change its contents depending on user agent.

@Bindestrich Code edited. User agent added. Makes no difference to the runtime behaviour

Is the domain you want to scrape indeed google, or is this a placeholder?

@Bindestrich The code shown is a Minimal Reproducible Example and therefore can be run exactly as shown

Often in my projects as I encounter such a problem I add such options. Often these are anti-bot security features.
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

I would also recommend using newer user agents this one is slightly outdated.
I would personally add in your code cleanly for debugging purposes.
driver.save_screenshot('your_screenshot_path')


Did you try adding your "answer" to the code shown in the question? Did it work? I tried your code and it changed the error into a timeout. That's probably because the user agent you recommend is for Windows systems whereas I'm on MacOS

yes I added it to the code at my place it worked flawlessly the only problem when I added a screenshot to debug it pops up a cookie confirmation window here .     bypass(driver)     driver.save_screenshot('your_screenshot_path.jpg')
I am using windows 11.

Why?
TLDR; a lot of sites have at least basic anti-bot mechanisms in place to read your browser info. This will include what flags your browser has set. Often times, a website will see the 'headless' flag and either completely block you or at least limit what you can see.
(This is also extends to the other answer which suggested a more up-to-date useragent as sometimes sites will block common bot or just old useragents)
Solving it
Another option you have besides those already suggested is to try using the Python package pyvirtualdisplay (pip install pyvirtualdisplay). This will simulate a screen your driver will display to, instead of setting the headless flag.
Very basic example:
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

with Display(visible = False, size = (1920, 1080)):
    with webdriver.Chrome(options = options) as driver:
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")


The only caveat is that this only works on Linux due to the requirements of the pyvirtualdisplay package. Otherwise you can run this in a Docker container (or slightly more difficultly through WSL).
